# Use config from other project in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration, visual-studio-2015

I have a web project which contains a Web.Config. When deploying that config, On Deployment (to Azure) VS modifies a setting (ClientId) inside that Config.

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="ClientId" value="123456123-beef-face-96ce-12346dd8a108" />
</appSettings>
```

Now I also have a console application that needs to use the same ClientId that has been created by deployment from the web application. To make things worse: I not just need the value from the the setting but is also has to be in the same structure in the App.config (appSettings/ClientId) . Both projects are in the same solution.

Is there a way to use the same config or automatically copy the setting from one config to the other when building/deploying?

Comment: Yes. Check <appSettings configSource="">

Comment: Sadly that does not work, because the ClientId is written automaticly into the web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way to do this:

First:

`<appSettings configSource="appSettings.config"/>;`

Property `configSource` use settings from other file

Second (code is good and compile)

Use like this:

```
[Test]
public void Publish_News_Post_From_File_Test()
{

    using (AppConfig.Change(@"otherFile.dll.config"))
    {
       //Now use other config file
    }
}
```

Source code:

```
public abstract class AppConfig : IDisposable
    {
        public static AppConfig Change(string path)
        {
            return new ChangeAppConfig(path);
        }

        public abstract void Dispose();

        private class ChangeAppConfig : AppConfig
        {
            private readonly string oldConfig =
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE").ToString();

            private bool disposedValue;

            public ChangeAppConfig(string path)
            {
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", path);
                ResetConfigMechanism();
            }

            public override void Dispose()
            {
                if (!disposedValue)
                {
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", oldConfig);
                    ResetConfigMechanism();

                    disposedValue = true;
                }
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }

            private static void ResetConfigMechanism()
            {
                typeof(ConfigurationManager)
                    .GetField("s_initState", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                             BindingFlags.Static)
                    .SetValue(null, 0);

                typeof(ConfigurationManager)
                    .GetField("s_configSystem", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                BindingFlags.Static)
                    .SetValue(null, null);

                typeof(ConfigurationManager)
                    .Assembly.GetTypes()
                    .Where(x => x.FullName ==
                                "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths")
                    .First()
                    .GetField("s_current", BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                           BindingFlags.Static)
                    .SetValue(null, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

In `using` stetment You may use other config file. I use it in test project to use the production web.config

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using another approach using Powershell (as a post-build):

```
$webconfig='C:\dev\mySolution\myWebProject\Web.config'
$appConfig='C:\dev\mySolution\myConsoleApp\App.config'

#Get Value from Web.Config:
$webconfigDoc=New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$webconfigDoc.Load($webconfig)
$webappsettings=$webconfigDoc.SelectSingleNode('//appSettings')
$webclientIdNode=$webappsettings.SelectSingleNode("//add[@key='ClientId']")
$clientId=$webclientIdNode.value

#Set Value into App.Config:
$appconfigDoc=New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$appconfigDoc.Load($appConfig)
$appsettings=$appconfigDoc.SelectSingleNode('//appSettings')
$appclientIdNode=$appsettings.SelectSingleNode("//add[@key='ClientId']")
$appclientIdNode.value=$clientId
$appconfigDoc.Save($appConfig)
```